# How to enable/disable a button based on boolean property within a tablerow

Tags: javafx

As the title states, I'm trying to enable/disable a button within a table row based upon a boolean within that table row's data. Here's my code so far:

```
col.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<ExampleRow, String>, TableCell<ExampleRow, String>>() {
        @Override
        public TableCell call(final TableColumn<ExampleRow, String> param){
            final Button btn = new Button("Save");
            final TableCell<ExampleRow, String> cell = new TableCell<ExampleRow, String>(){

                @Override
                public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty){
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if(empty){
                        setGraphic(null);
                        setText(null);
                    } else {
                        btn.setPrefWidth(col.getWidth());
                        btn.setPadding(Insets.EMPTY);
                        btn.setOnAction(event -> {

                        });
                        setGraphic(btn);
                        setText(null);
                    }
                }
            };
            ExampleRow row = (ExampleRow)cell.getTableRow().getItem(); //NPE here
            btn.setDisable(!row.hasChanged());
            return cell;
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately my code breaks on the fifth from the bottom line. If I exclude that line and change the line below to `btn.setDisable(true)` it works wonderfully. What can I do to disable this button based upon the data in which the button resides?

Comment: What is the `String` property that you are using for this column (i.e. the value that is passed as the `item` to the `updateItem` method)? It doesn't look like you are using it. If not, why not make the column a `TableColumn<ExampleRow, Boolean>` and make the cell's value the `changed` property of `ExampleRow`? Then you can just change the disabled state of the button directly in the `updateItem` method.

Comment: This was just an unused dummy String that I was using at the suggestion of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489366/how-to-add-button-in-javafx-table-view) question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't using the item anyways, so you could just make it a `Boolean` and use the value of the `changed` property. This allows you to enable/disable the button in the `updateItem` method:

Example:

```
public static class Item {
    private final BooleanProperty changed = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

    public final boolean isChanged() {
        return this.changed.get();
    }

    public final void setChanged(boolean value) {
        this.changed.set(value);
    }

    public final BooleanProperty changedProperty() {
        return this.changed;
    }

}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TableView<Item> table = new TableView();
    table.getItems().addAll(new Item(), new Item(), new Item());

    TableColumn<Item, Boolean> column = new TableColumn<>();
    column.setCellValueFactory(cd -> cd.getValue().changedProperty());
    column.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<Item, Boolean>() {

        final Button btn = new Button("Save");

        {
            btn.setOnAction(evt -> {
                Item item = (Item) getTableRow().getItem();
                item.setChanged(false);
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty || item == null) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                btn.setDisable(!item);
                setGraphic(btn);
            }
        }

    });

    table.getColumns().add(column);

    Button btn = new Button("change");
    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        Item item = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        if (item != null) {
            item.setChanged(true);
        }
    });

    VBox root = new VBox(btn, table);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

---

BTW: `TableView` uses the `cellFactory` to create the cells. The `item`, `table` and `tableRow` properties are updated later. Therefore retrieving any of those values in the `cellFactory`'s `call` method itself makes no sense, since none of those values have been assigned at that time.