# Button doesnot displayed in tablecolumn in java-fx

Tags: button, tablecolumn

Here is code: Contoller class:
`@FXML private TableView<User> table;
  @FXML private   TableColumn<User,String> view;`

method() {.....
         `  view.setCellValueFactory(
                    new PropertyValueFactory("DUMMY"));

```
        Callback<TableColumn<User, String>, TableCell<User, String>> cellFactory
                = new Callback<TableColumn<User, String>, TableCell<User, String>>() {
            public TableCell call( TableColumn<User, String> param) {
                final TableCell<User, String> cell = new TableCell<User, String>() {

                    Button btn = new Button("View");

                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (empty) {
                            setGraphic(null);
                            setText(null);
                        } else {
                            btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                                public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                                User user = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
                                System.out.println(user.username
                                        + "   " + user.name);
                                }
                            });

                            setGraphic(btn);
                            setText(null);
                        }
                    }
                };
                return cell;
            }
        };

        view.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
       //add observablelist
       table.getItems().setAll(datas);
}`
```

I have borrowed code from here: [How to add button in JavaFX table view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489366/how-to-add-button-in-javafx-table-view)
Indeed I have nothing do view in my View column.
Compiler complains that I cannot use parameterless new PropertyValueFactory<>("DUMMY")) in jdk 1.7
Moreover why I cannot use such expression for button column @FXML private TableColumn view?
I also should note that I changed original code with lambda (possible just in 1.8).

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Obviously, java.  I changed the original code just by using standart button event handling instead lambda expression. And not used PropertyValueFactory<> but PropertyValueFactory<User,String>,but why not use PropertyValueFactory<User, Button>? Anyway why it doesnt work.

Comment: Obviuosly in original link there is some misinformation.

Comment: In original code there is cue that changes needs -- at first -- that one = // - just to delete comment. Indeed to display button you need put in PropertyValueFactory<>("DUMMY")) instead DUMMY some not empty property even you used for another string column - for example "username" that has at least getUsername() getter with username field, if java-fx property is not present.