# How to create a button which if it's clicked, it expands and shows details?

Tags: java, button, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I have this table, where there are several entries with an orderID.

[image]

To show more informations about the entry, you can click on the but
[image]

Is this think doable with javafx Scene Builder? What should I do?

The suggestion about TitledPane is good, but how can I insert it into a table? As you can see here, it's like "separated".

[image]

Comment: Have you attempted to use `TitledPane` to see if it is good enough for you?

Comment: hi, @Sedrick thanks . But how can I insert this TItledPane inside a table?

Comment: One question per post. Please make an attempt first and if you run into a problem come back with a question. Your question can't change as you get suggestions to the original question.

Comment: `setCellFactory` -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489366/how-to-add-button-in-javafx-table-view